# Cobol-Restart from the program

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

I have a little question
I wrote a calculator in cobol, and I'm not so expert
I give you here the code:

```
       DISPLAY "CALCOLATRICE".
       DISPLAY "ATTENZIONE, IL RISULTATO NON HA SEGNI!".
       DISPLAY "CHE VUOI FARE?".
       DISPLAY "1 ADDIZIONE".
       DISPLAY "2 SOTTRAZIONE".
       DISPLAY "3 MOLTIPLICAZIONE".
       DISPLAY "4 DIVISIONE". 
       DISPLAY "5 ESCI"
       ACCEPT INPUT1

       IF INPUT1 = 5
            DISPLAY "OK, BUON LAVORO :)"
            STOP RUN
        END-IF.

       IF INPUT1 = 1
       DISPLAY "PRIMO NUMERO"
       ACCEPT A
       DISPLAY "SECONDO NUMERO"
       ACCEPT B
       COMPUTE C= A + B
               DISPLAY "Computing"
               DISPLAY "Computing."
               DISPLAY "Computing.."
               DISPLAY "Computing..."
               DISPLAY "Computing...."
               DISPLAY "Computing....."
               DISPLAY "Computing......"
               DISPLAY A "+" B  " FA..."         
               DISPLAY C
       ELSE
           IF INPUT1 = 2
               DISPLAY "PRIMO NUMERO"
               ACCEPT A
               DISPLAY "SECONDO NUMERO"
               ACCEPT B
               DISPLAY "Computing"
               DISPLAY "Computing."
               DISPLAY "Computing.."
               DISPLAY "Computing..."
               DISPLAY "Computing...."
               DISPLAY "Computing....."
               DISPLAY "Computing......"
               DISPLAY A "-" B " FA..."
               COMPUTE C= A - B
               DISPLAY C
                   ELSE
                       IF INPUT1 = 3 
                   DISPLAY "PRIMO NUMERO"
                   ACCEPT A
                   DISPLAY "SECONDO NUMERO"
                   ACCEPT B
                   COMPUTE C= A * B
                          DISPLAY "Computing"
                          DISPLAY "Computing."
                          DISPLAY "Computing.."
                          DISPLAY "Computing..."
                          DISPLAY "Computing...."
                          DISPLAY "Computing....."
                          DISPLAY "Computing......"
                          DISPLAY A "x" B " FA..."
                          DISPLAY C
                       ELSE
                           IF INPUT1 = 4
                           DISPLAY "PRIMO NUMERO"
                           ACCEPT A
                           DISPLAY "SECONDO NUMERO"
                           ACCEPT B
                           COMPUTE C= A / B
                          DISPLAY "Computing."
               DISPLAY "Computing.."
               DISPLAY "Computing..."
               DISPLAY "Computing...."
               DISPLAY "Computing....."
               DISPLAY "Computing......"
               DISPLAY A ":" B " FA..."
                           DISPLAY C
            END-IF
           END-IF
         END-IF
       END-IF.
       STOP RUN.
```

Now, I want to give a message saying "Do you want to do other operations?" and, if the answer is yes it returns to the beginning, and if you say no it goes to the end.
If you can explain to me how, but not with paragraphs if you can. Can I have the code correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, I want to give a message saying "Do you want to do other operations?" and, if the answer is yes it returns to the beginning, and if you say no it goes to the end. If you can explain to me how, but not with paragraphs if you can. Can I have the code correct?

```
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 INPUT1 PIC 9.
   01 A PIC 9(4).
   01 B PIC 9(4).
   01 C PIC 9(4).
   01 Q PIC X VALUE "N".
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       PERFORM WITH TEST AFTER UNTIL INPUT1 = 5 OR Q = "N" OR "n"
           DISPLAY "CALCOLATRICE"
           DISPLAY "ATTENZIONE, IL RISULTATO NON HA SEGNI!"
           DISPLAY "CHE VUOI FARE?"
           DISPLAY "1 ADDIZIONE"
           DISPLAY "2 SOTTRAZIONE"
           DISPLAY "3 MOLTIPLICAZIONE"
           DISPLAY "4 DIVISIONE"
           DISPLAY "5 ESCI"
           ACCEPT INPUT1

           EVALUATE INPUT1
           WHEN 1
               DISPLAY "PRIMO NUMERO"
               ACCEPT A
               DISPLAY "SECONDO NUMERO"
               ACCEPT B
               COMPUTE C= A + B
               DISPLAY "Computing"
               DISPLAY "Computing."
               DISPLAY "Computing.."
               DISPLAY "Computing..."
               DISPLAY "Computing...."
               DISPLAY "Computing....."
               DISPLAY "Computing......"
               DISPLAY A "+" B  " FA..."
               DISPLAY C
           WHEN 2
               DISPLAY "PRIMO NUMERO"
               ACCEPT A
               DISPLAY "SECONDO NUMERO"
               ACCEPT B
               DISPLAY "Computing"
               DISPLAY "Computing."
               DISPLAY "Computing.."
               DISPLAY "Computing..."
               DISPLAY "Computing...."
               DISPLAY "Computing....."
               DISPLAY "Computing......"
               DISPLAY A "-" B " FA..."
               COMPUTE C= A - B
               DISPLAY C
           WHEN 3
               DISPLAY "PRIMO NUMERO"
               ACCEPT A
               DISPLAY "SECONDO NUMERO"
               ACCEPT B
               COMPUTE C= A * B
               DISPLAY "Computing"
               DISPLAY "Computing."
               DISPLAY "Computing.."
               DISPLAY "Computing..."
               DISPLAY "Computing...."
               DISPLAY "Computing....."
               DISPLAY "Computing......"
               DISPLAY A "x" B " FA..."
               DISPLAY C
           WHEN 4
               DISPLAY "PRIMO NUMERO"
               ACCEPT A
               DISPLAY "SECONDO NUMERO"
               ACCEPT B
               COMPUTE C= A / B
               DISPLAY "Computing."
               DISPLAY "Computing.."
               DISPLAY "Computing..."
               DISPLAY "Computing...."
               DISPLAY "Computing....."
               DISPLAY "Computing......"
               DISPLAY A ":" B " FA..."
               DISPLAY C
           WHEN 5
               DISPLAY "OK, BUON LAVORO :)"
           END-EVALUATE
           IF INPUT1 NOT = 5
               DISPLAY "Do you want to do other operations?"
               ACCEPT Q
           END-IF
       END-PERFORM
       STOP RUN
       .
```

Answer (score 0):

Outline:

```
MOVE 'Y' TO do_work
PERFORM UNTIL do_work <> 'Y'
   display menu
   get response
   EVALUATE response
      WHEN reponse = 5
         MOVE 'N' to do_work
      /* other response processing */
   END-PERFORM
GOBACK.
```

Comment: I changed If to WHEN to make it more Cobol like