# Command Wait in COBOL?

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

Is there a kind of "Wait" function in COBOL?
I wrote a calculator, and to make it more 50s, i Print " Computing." "Computing.." ecc
For example:

```
                   DISPLAY "SECONDO NUMERO"
                   ACCEPT B
                   COMPUTE C= A * B
                          DISPLAY "Computing"
                          DISPLAY "Computing."
                          DISPLAY "Computing.."
                          DISPLAY "Computing..."
                          DISPLAY "Computing...."
                          DISPLAY "Computing....."
                          DISPLAY "Computing......"
                          DISPLAY A "x" B " FA..."
                          DISPLAY C
```

Now, is there a way to make a little delay (half a second) on COBOL where I put the "Computing" piece? I created a github repo (https://github.com/aIDserse/Super-utility-Submachine-COBOL-CALCULATOR) to this project, look at it (refer to version 1.3) for the complete code (and maybye spread it hahah). Thx!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no wait statement in any ISO Standard COBOL.

However, if you got built in [system routines](https://open-cobol.sourceforge.io/doc/gnucobol.html#System-Routines) available either C$SLEEP (for seconds) or CBL_GC_NANOSLEEP (for nanoseconds) should do the trick.

Example (sleeps for half a second):

```
call "CBL_GC_NANOSLEEP" using "500000000" end-call
```

For IBM's Enterprise COBOL (LE enabled) the CEE3DLY routine is most suitable (there are also other legacy routines available).

Answer (score 6):

There is a statement for sleeping in standard COBOL, but only with [COBOL 202x](https://web.archive.org/web/20221208145929/https://isotc.iso.org/livelink/livelink/nfetch/-8918758/8918781/8918784/21916208/ISO-IEC_JTC_1-SC_22-WG_4_N1449_CDG-22-0062_-_DIS_COBOL_2022_std.pdf?nodeid=22377830&vernum=0):

```
           CONTINUE AFTER arithmetic-expression SECONDS
```

As this standard is in the committee draft state it is hard to find an implementation, but as you've asked for GnuCOBOL - GnuCOBOL 3.1 already implements it.

Other than this there are some dialect specific library routines that can be used, like `CALL "C$SLEEP"` originating from ACUCOBOL-GT (also implemented with GnuCOBOL, but be aware that pre 3.1-versions only use the non-decimal part, so `"0.9"` will sleep zero seconds).

For OpenCOBOL/GnuCOBOL you can call the [`CBL_OC_NANOSLEEP`/`CBL_GC_NANOSLEEP`](https://open-cobol.sourceforge.io/faq/index.html#what-is-cbl-oc-nanosleep) library routines.

For any COBOL environment that can call native routines you have variants of [`CALL "sleep"`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/sleep).

As [mentioned by Rick Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61861269/5027456) Many COBOL implementations also implement a callable `SYSTEM` where you may use something like a `ping localhost` with a timeout, but whatever you call may not be available (or the process running the COBOL environment has no access to it).

Stephen Gennard [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61860838/command-wait-in-cobol#comment109449004_61876759) a very common extension:

```
           ACCEPT something WITH TIMEOUT
```

which has a "beware" that different environments use a different scale (some seconds, some milliseconds). This has the pro/con that the user can "break" out by pressing a key (normally a function key); and the additional issue that it may only work in "graphical" environments.

Anton's answer highlights the IBM library routine [`CEE3DLY`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.ceea300/clc3dly.htm).

Answer (score 1):

There is no wait or delay statement in standard COBOL. There may be, for GnuCOBOL, a `CALL "SYSTEM"` to effect a delay.

I took some code that I use for elapsed time measurement and modified the code to create a procedure for a delay.

Wherever you need a delay, insert the statement `PERFORM timed-delay`. Of course, the delay may be changed. This code is set to work even if the delay crosses midnight.

Code:

```
   working-storage section.
   01 t pic 9(8).
   01 t-start.
     03 t-start-hour pic 99.
     03 t-start-minute pic 99.
     03 t-start-second pic 99v99.
   01 t-end.
     03 t-end-hour pic 99.
     03 t-end-minute pic 99.
     03 t-end-second pic 99v99.
   77 t-elapsed pic 9(7)v99.
   procedure division.
   begin.
       accept t from time
       display t
       perform timed-delay
       accept t from time
       display t
       stop run
       .

   timed-delay.
       accept t-start from time
       move 0 to t-elapsed
       perform until t-elapsed > 0.5   *> one-half second
           accept t-end from time
           perform get-elapsed
       end-perform
       .

   get-elapsed.
       if t-start > t-end
           move 86400 to t-elapsed
       else
           move 0 to t-elapsed
       end-if
       compute t-elapsed = t-elapsed
         + (t-end-hour - t-start-hour) * 3600
         + (t-end-minute - t-start-minute) * 60
         + (t-end-second - t-start-second)
       end-compute
       .
```

Output: (shows a delay of 0.55 seconds)

```
21424364
21424419
```

---

The initial `PERFORM WITH TEST AFTER ...` is nothing like the code I provided in: [Cobol-Restart from the program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61796161/9170346) , so I turned it into comments. It should be removed.

If you want to use `SLEEP-SEC` instead of a fixed value, replace the `0.5` with `SLEEP-SEC`; but provide a `VALUE` clause for `SLEEP-SEC` or `MOVE` a value to it before the displaying the menu.

For example, in your code (with most code removed):

```
   DATA DIVISION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  SLEEP-SEC PIC S9(2)V9(2).
   01  A PIC S9(7)V9(7).
   01  B PIC S9(7)V9(7).
   01  C PIC S9(7)V9(7).
   01  D PIC S9(11)V9(7).
   01  INPUT1 PIC 9(14).
   01  Q PIC X VALUE "Y".
   01 t-start.
     03 t-start-hour pic 99.
     03 t-start-minute pic 99.
     03 t-start-second pic 99v99.
   01 t-end.
     03 t-end-hour pic 99.
     03 t-end-minute pic 99.
     03 t-end-second pic 99v99.
   77 t-elapsed pic 9(7)v99.

       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   MAIN.
  *    PERFORM WITH TEST AFTER
  *        UNTIL Q ="YES" OR "Y" OR "y" OR "yes" OR "Yes"
  *    END-PERFORM.
       DISPLAY "CALCULATOR".
       DISPLAY "WHAT DO YOU WANT DO DO?".
       DISPLAY "1 ADDITION".
       DISPLAY "15 EXIT"
       DISPLAY "CHOOSE AN OPTION"
       ACCEPT INPUT1
       EVALUATE  INPUT1

       WHEN = 15
            DISPLAY "OK, GOOD JOB :)"
            STOP RUN

       WHEN = 1
       DISPLAY "FIRST NUMBER"
       ACCEPT A
       DISPLAY "SECOND NUMBER"
       ACCEPT B
       COMPUTE C= A + B
               DISPLAY "Computing"
       PERFORM timed-delay
               DISPLAY "(" A ")" "+" "(" B ")" "RESULTS..."
               DISPLAY C

       END-EVALUATE

               IF INPUT1 NOT = 15
           DISPLAY "DO YOU WANT TO DO OTHER CALCULATIONS?"
           ACCEPT Q
           IF Q = "YES" OR "Y" OR "y" OR "yes" OR "Yes" GO TO MAIN
               ELSE DISPLAY "OK, GOOD JOB :)"
              END-IF
              STOP RUN.

   timed-delay.
       accept t-start from time
       move 0 to t-elapsed
       perform until t-elapsed > 0.5   *> one-half second
           accept t-end from time
           perform get-elapsed
       end-perform
       .

   get-elapsed.
       if t-start > t-end
           move 86400 to t-elapsed
       else
           move 0 to t-elapsed
       end-if
       compute t-elapsed = t-elapsed
         + (t-end-hour - t-start-hour) * 3600
         + (t-end-minute - t-start-minute) * 60
         + (t-end-second - t-start-second)
       end-compute
       .
```

Answer (score 1):

For GnuCobol call the C$SLEEP with the number of seconds you want to wait.

```
CALL "C$SLEEP" USING 2 END-CALL
```

COBOL has no build in language feature to handle waiting.  This is a system specific request and I believe always requires calling an external module to interface with said system.